# Rails 3.1 recommended practice for managing library javascripts

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm curious what is the recommend approach for organizing and using library javascripts (things like Backbone, Underscore, Modernizr, etc.) in Rails.  I've noticed a number of different practices so it seems to get a bit confusing.

There are a number of gems that provide the ability to bundle things like Modernizr, Backbone, Underscore, etc.  Is this a preferred approach for cases where a gem exists?

For cases where a gem doesn't exist would it make sense to use the /public folder or the /app/assets/javascripts and go via the pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take a look at the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization) for this question.

> Assets can be placed inside an application in one of three locations:
> app/assets, lib/assets or vendor/assets.
>
> app/assets is for assets that are owned by the application, such as
> custom images, JavaScript files or stylesheets.
>
> lib/assets is for your own libraries’ code that doesn’t really fit
> into the scope of the application or those libraries which are shared
> across applications.
>
> vendor/assets is for assets that are owned by outside entities, such
> as code for JavaScript plugins.

What I would do is place all the JS files that you dont maintain is vendor/assets, if this folder is missing you can just create it. And as far as using gems for your assets thats usually fine for larger frameworks and libraries like jQuery however I would shy away from them for stuff like Backbone.js and others just to keep the gemfile clean and reduce some bloat you might see with that.

If you need any clarification let me know and good luck with your application.

Comment: Thanks that was what I was wondering.  I wasn't in love with using Gems either.

Comment: Yep, Ive seen my fair share of projects where the creator went overboard with the gems, IMO its just better to use the versions provided by the creators of the library. This goes for external services as well like the Google Maps JS API.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add something (the answer of @DevinM is wonderful), here are my thoughts about using JavaScript in Rails:

- If there is a Gem that bundles a JavaScript library (like `jquery-rails`) I would stick to that:

  - Keeps the library away from your code.
  - Adds the libraries automatically to rails (or at least explains how to do that).
  - Helps you to update the library automatically through `bundle update` if you want to.
- If there is no integration by a Gem, keep it under `vendor/assets` as described:

  - Ensures that the library is known as external.
  - Document the need to that library somewhere (e.g. in your `application.js` file)
- Your own libraries in `lib/assets` as described.
- `application.js` or the controller dependent `*.js` files in your `app/assets/javascripts` folder.
- Use `application.js` mostly for wiring, that means how to integrate the other libraries into your application. Explain there what the code means: used library, reference to documentation, meaning of configuration.

My experience is that after some time, you don't remember what the reason for a library was, so some house-keeping helps you stay healthy.